# Lua VS Code: Is there a tool that can replace a variable or a function until it gets redefined?

Tags: visual-studio-code, lua

Is there an extension or an application that can replace a variable or a function until it gets redefined?

Code:

```
function Test(arg)
  print("[Damnn] " .. arg)
end
Test("Super test")
Test("asd")

function Test()
  return false
end
if Test() then
  print("True")
else
  print("False")
end
```

Replaced code:

```
function Foo(arg)
  print("[Damnn] " .. arg)
end
Foo("Super test")
Foo("asd")

function Test()
  return false
end
if Test() then
  print("True")
else
  print("False")
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing `Test(arg)` with `Foo(arg)` will not interfer with `Test()`.

This can be done with the search and replace feature. There is no need for some plugin.